# How do I access a UserControl resource from a .net class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, resourcedictionary

I am trying to access a resource in a `UserControl` from my `TreeViewGroupItemTemplateSelector` class.  I do not have access to the `UserControl` class within the `TreeViewGroupItemTemplateSelector` class.  I am having problems formatting the `Uri`.

`PackageExplorer.xaml` is the `UserControl` and resides in the root namespace of the local assembly which also contains the `TreeViewGroupItemTemplateSelector` class.

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot locate resource 'resources/packageexplorer.xaml'

During the instantiation of the Uri.

```
public class TreeViewGroupItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var configGroup = item as IConfigurationGroup;
            if (configGroup == null)
                return null;
            var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            resourceDictionary.Source = new Uri
               ("/myAssembly;component/Resources/myUserControl.xaml",
               UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            if (configGroup.ItemType == typeof (ReferencePackageConfigurationItem))
                return resourceDictionary["RefreshableHierarchicalDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            else
                return resourceDictionary["DefaultHierarchicalDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

        }
    }
}
```

The XAML (snippet) looks as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="DefaultHierarchicalDataTemplate" 
            DataType="{x:Type localconfig:ConfigurationGroup}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" 
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewGroupItemTemplateSelector}"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="RefreshableHierarchicalDataTemplate" 
            DataType="{x:Type localconfig:ConfigurationGroup}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" 
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewGroupItemTemplateSelector}"/>
```

I've also tried accessing the resource as shown below with the same results:

```
    resourceDictionary.Source = new 
         Uri("/Resources/myUserControl.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

and:

```
resourceDictionary.Source = new 
     Uri("myUserControl.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: Pete, try putting resources outside the user control (merge it into user control instead, or have it globally visible) - and then try loading that resource dictionary instead of the user control.

Comment: @NSGaga, the above comment is a little confusing.  1) I have no need for this resource except for in this control and the TemplateClass (used from within the control).  Why would I move it?  2) You recommended moving it outside the user control and to merge it into user control instead?

Comment: yes Pete - it's not clear what you're trying to achieve - as I understand, you're trying to load the entire user-control XAML file - as a resource, right ? User control XAML is not a 'resource dictionary' - I'm not sure as to what error that'd produce. But to be sure just separate things. You can use the `MergeDictionary` to merge any outside 'resource dictionary' XAML into `UserControl.Resources` - but keep that 'resource' as file on its own - load that, not entire user control, hope it makes sense now

Comment: Ahh.. ok, thanks @NSGaga. I was under the assumption that resources in a UserControl were accessible from outside the control. I moved to a separate resource file and that works. :)

Comment: great @Pete - you should mark this as an answer then - I just posted what I said in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not clear what you're trying to achieve - but as I understand...

> If you're trying to load the entire user-control XAML file - as a resource
>
> User control XAML is not a 'resource dictionary' - I'm not sure as to what error that might produce.

But **just separate things**. You can use the MergeDictionary to merge any outside 'resource dictionary' XAML into UserControl.Resources - but keep that 'resource' as file on its own - load that, not entire user control, hope that helps